# MudBlazor/MudTable fix table height

Tags: c#, css, blazor, mudblazor

I am using MudBlazor and want to fix the height of the table so the page size footer is anchored to the bottom of the container if the search results show less rows that the page size.

For example, this is a normal table:

[image: Normal]

when searching and less than 10 records exist the table appears smaller:

[image: searched table]

I've tried using the Height attribute on the MudTable tag but this forces a scroll bar if the user changes the page size.

The behaviour I am looking for is the page size footer remains in the same place if the row number falls below the page size settings.

If there any css I can override to achieve this.  It would make the visual look much better.

Edit:
Here is a basic code snippet as requested.
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/waGokwYIcbquRxRe

2nd Edit:
Here it is inside a dialog
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wOGeuGYImQAWoahb

Here the the table definition (as a razor component):

```
<MudTable Elevation="1" Striped="false" Bordered="true" Hover="true" Items="@data" T="CountriesDetail" Filter="new Func<CountriesDetail,bool>(SearchFunction)">
    <ToolBarContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Color="Color.Primary">Countries</MudText>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudTextField @bind-Value="searchString" Immediate="true" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
    </ToolBarContent>
    <NoRecordsContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body1" Class="mud-text-secondary mt-6 mb-4">No data to display</MudText>
    </NoRecordsContent>
    <ColGroup>
       <col style="width: 100%" />
    </ColGroup>
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Country Name</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.CountryName</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudTablePager/>
    </PagerContent>
</MudTable>

@code {
  public class CountriesDetail
    {   
        public string ID { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string CountryName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    private List<CountriesDetail> data = new();

    private string searchString = string.Empty;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        data.Add(new() { ID = "1", CountryName = "Country 1" });
        data.Add(new() { ID = "2", CountryName = "Country 2" });
        data.Add(new() { ID = "3", CountryName = "Country 3" });
        data.Add(new() { ID = "4", CountryName = "Country 4" });
        data.Add(new() { ID = "5", CountryName = "Country 5" });
        data.Add(new() { ID = "6", CountryName = "Country 6" });
        data.Add(new() { ID = "7", CountryName = "Country 7" });
        data.Add(new() { ID = "8", CountryName = "Country 8" });
        data.Add(new() { ID = "9", CountryName = "Country 9" });
        data.Add(new() { ID = "10", CountryName = "Country 10" });
        data.Add(new() { ID = "11", CountryName = "Country 11" });
        data.Add(new() { ID = "12", CountryName = "Country 12" });
    }
    private bool SearchFunction(CountriesDetail element) => PerformSearch(element, searchString);
    
    private bool PerformSearch(CountriesDetail element, string searchString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString)) return true;
        if (element.CountryName.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return true;
        
        return false;
    }

}
```

Here is the dialog:

```
<MudDialog>
    <TitleContent>
        <MudText>Country Search</MudText>
    </TitleContent>
    <DialogContent>
            <TableDef></TableDef>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
    </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>
```

And here is how it gets called:

```
@inject IDialogService DialogService


<MudButton OnClick="@LoadDialog">Go</MudButton>


@code{
  
  private void LoadDialog()
  {
        var options = new DialogOptions { CloseOnEscapeKey = true };
        DialogService.Show<Dialog>("", options);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**

Comment: added as requested

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and **[not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `vh` CSS unit in the `Height` property of `MudTable`. `vh` is viewport height, which is the relative to the screen height.

```html
<MudTable Items="@Elements" Height="60vh" ... >
<!--  -->
</MudTable>
```

Here in the example I set it to `60vh` which essentially means 60% of the entire window/screen height. So the scroll bar won't be forced.
[MudTable on it's own snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cOGoamYxidDzHmXz)

---

In the case of the table being in another container, and you want to restrict it to it's parent container and not the screen then, you can use the **%** unit.

There's a few things you have to do to set this up. `%` unit is relative to the immediate parent. The `Height` property of `MudTable` sets the `height` css property of the content only, so that means that we need to set the dialog height to a `vh` unit, the table `Style` to a `%` unit and finally the `Height` of the content to a `%` unit.

For example,

```
<div class="my-dialog" style="height:60vh;">
    <div class="my-table" style="height:100%;">
        <div class="my-table-content" style="height:60%;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[MudTable in Dialog snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mumeacuSHiEzzGNu)

Comment: Thanks RBee, this does work except when the table is used in a  MudDialog as the vh returns the parent height not the dialog height.  When the table is used on a normal page the shrinking behaviour is not as much as an issue.  When it's in a dialog the whole dialog changes.  I can fix the dialog height but it would look cleaner if the table didnt change instead.  Any further ideas?

Comment: @user21415940 Can you update your question with a snippet with your setup? You can use my demo snippet as a starting point.

Comment: added as requested

Comment: that is exactly what I wanted - thank you very much for that.  the table looks much better now.